# Inserting of cols (Vue/Javascript function) in Bootstrap row, for loop not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to finish a function to insert cols in to a Bootstrap row using Vue/javascript, but have got stuck at the second part, which is the insertion on childnodes. The loop is not working wherever I put the index, Ive tried a few ways but no joy. Its is to insert a swatch in to the row,and in subsequent columns afterwards. The first swatch is fine. The cols are col-md-3, so 4 across Code is below. Statement works for the first insertion, but fails at the next stage.

// Conditional statement to check if swatch exists before insertion

```
  let swatch = document.querySelector('.row');
  let element = document.getElementById("bg-gradient");
  //If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
  if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
    let i;
    swatch = document.querySelector('.row').children[i];
    for (i = 0; i < swatch.length[0]; i++) {
    swatch[i].appendChild(newSwatch);
    gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
    textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;
    }
    } else {
    // First swatch in first row.
    swatch.appendChild(newSwatch);
    gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
    textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;
  }
```

[image]

```
HTML before swatches, in to an empty row:

<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
  <h3>Your Gradients</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
 </div>
  </div>

With swatch added 

<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
  <h3>Your Gradients</h3><br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div id="bg-gradient">

  </div>
  <div id="info">

  </div>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

How to fix the loop so it inserts the swatches in each next col-md-3 position, OR, I did think of trying a test to see if the id  bg-gradient exists in if statement as that's the id of the div containing the actual gradient and might be better way of doing it instead of the for loop? What is the best way to test for that id #bg-gradient if that might work, as a slight variation of the existing  check on it?
https://github.com/xhostcom/vue-gradient-swatch-generator.git

Any tips welcome, Thanks

Comment: I think it would be useful to show the html before the swatches are added and what you want it to be after.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes have done now Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update I fixed this now, it was fairly simple didn't need a loop, just the conditional statement in the saveSwatch function

```
// Conditional statement to check if swatch exists before insertion
      let swatch = document.querySelector('.row');
      let element = document.getElementById("bg-gradient");
      //If it isn't "undefined" and it isn't "null", then it exists.
      if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
        swatch.appendChild(newSwatch);
        gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
        textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;
        } else {
        // First swatch in first row.
        swatch.appendChild(newSwatch);
        gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
        textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;
       }
    },
```

This inserts the first and subsequent swatches OK.

I still have a small problem on empty row though, it inserts the empty vales, so trying a checkSwatch function which I cant get work yet, to run at the start of saveSwatch function on click, its below.

```
 checkSwatch() {
        let swatch = document.querySelector('.row');
          if(swatch.children <= 0) {
             console.log("Check Swatch Still  Works")
          }
        console.log("Check Swatch Works")
    },
      saveSwatch() {
         this.checkSwatch()
      console.log("Save Works");
      this.createSwatch();
    },
```

Cant get the conditional right on this one I just want to stop it inserting anything if there is no gradient set.

Couldn't see the wood for the trees on this one!. The target div is a bootstrap row, so EVERY swatch is a children, and they are all empty before insertion, so  a for loop and incrementing is not needed! Just need a check to stop insertion of a col with no contents ie the gradient.

Any tips welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you still haven't provided enough detail.  Are you trying to create html like this?

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
 <h3>Your Gradients</h3><br>
 <div class="row">
  <!-- swatch #1 -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div id="bg-gradient">...</div>
  </div>
  <!-- swatch #2 -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div id="bg-gradient">...</div>
  </div>
  <!-- swatch #3 -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div id="bg-gradient">...</div>
  </div>
  <!-- swatch #4 -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div id="bg-gradient">...</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <!-- swatch #5 -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <div id="bg-gradient">...</div>
  </div>
  ... more swatches ...
 </div>
</div>
```

Which will create a color swatch like this using a bootstrap grid?

```
#########################################
# Color 1 # Color 2 # Color 3 # Color 4 #
#########################################
# Color 5 # Color 6 # Color 7 # Color 8 #
#########################################
```

If you simplify the logic to add the newSwatch to this does it do what you want?

```
let swatch = document.querySelector('.row');
swatch.appendChild(newSwatch);
gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
textDiv.innerHTML = '<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>';
```

I don't see a need to check for the existence of an element with id = bg-gradient since you are adding it as part of the new swatch

Comment: Yip, thats it, I tried this manually one at a time on a html mockup and successfully  about 12 cols of swatches cols of 4, so they will continue to insert as the grid gets larger after the first one has been added, Ive also swapped to .children as that just gets the element which is what I want. but still getting error can read property length of undefined. The html above is just the first col, and we just keep adding those in the grid.Thanks

Comment: Also there is not another row, in test it just kept creating swathes in the same row below the others. seemed fine

Comment: I  changed the loop again took out the i in children, and this time no length error, but also not doing anything, seems close but not quite there.  if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
        let i;
        swatch = document.querySelector('.row').children;
        for (i = 0; i < swatch.length[0]; i++) {
        swatch.appendChild(newSwatch);
        gradDiv.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
        textDiv.innerHTML = `<h5>${hexValues}</h5><p>${hexValues}</p>`;
        }

Comment: Looks like I should be using children to detect the subsequent col-md-3's so it just keeps adding them, which would be fine, but cant get the test to work in that loop.  Maybe I should also give also give an id to the col-md-3 and not just the  div inside. Temp demo is at http://pretty-manager.surge.sh/ Thanks